# Using ASP.NET 5 with Visual Studio 2013 Community Edition

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-core

I am interested in evaluating ASP.NET 5. I have installed Visual Studio 2013 - Community Edition. I am now trying to following the example provided [here](http://www.asp.net/vnext/overview/aspnet-vnext/vc).That example uses Visual Studio 2015 Preview. Is there a Visual Studio Template for ASP.NET 5 for Visual Studio 2013 - Community Edition?

I cannot find one.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ASP.NET 5 (vNext) isn't supported in Visual Studio 2013. If you want to test ASP.NET 5, you should [install Visual Studio 2015](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs-2015-product-editions).

Another option is to test [ASP.NET 5 on a Mac](https://www.jeremymorgan.com/tutorials/vnext/how-to-build-c-sharp-on-mac-osx/) or [Linux machine](http://www.omnisharp.net/). I was able to get it working on a Mac without too much hassle, and having Intellisense in Sublime Text was really cool.

Or, as [Victor Hurdugaci](https://stackoverflow.com/users/149064/victor-hurdugaci) points out, you don't need Visual Studio on Windows at all to run ASP.NET 5. The [OmniSharp project](http://www.omnisharp.net/) has alternatives to Visual Studio listed, along with directions for setting them up.

Comment: An additional point: even on Windows you don't need VS 2015. Actually, you don't need any VS at all to create an ASP.NET vNext app.

Answer (score 0):

You may develop Asp.net 5/Asp.net core with the help of Visual Studio Code Without Installing VS2015